# Calculate best area with overlaying multiple layers buffer shapes

Tags: qgis, layers, overlay

I am using QGIS and I have a set of 20 layers with buffers. I'm interested in where they overlap most and I want to create a single layer that shows which are the places where they overlap most and how much. Somehow I already achieved the visual result changing the color and the transparency of the layers but I want just one layer that tells me how many layers are overlapping on a specific area.

Is it possible?

Comment: Have you tried something like an Intersect tool?

Answer (score 1):

Ok looking for help in finishing this answer as i think it is almost there.

if you have two layers and want to find out what portion of the buffers lie within the other then i would simply use the "clip" function to clip layer 2 to what is within layer one.[image]
See the image.

To do this on a larger level i am imagining you would have needed to create your buffers with the "disolve buffer results" checked.

After this i am stumped...as in how to apply across 20 od layers at once.

Comment: Easiest way is just to use the batch processing functionalities from the Processing toolbox